# Nonnegative determinant of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Consider the following matrix with nonnegative entries:
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ b & c & d & e \\ c & d & e & f \\ d & e & f & g \\ \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Can we prove that, if each minor $2\times 2$ has nonnegative determinant, then the determinant of $M$ itself is nonnegative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer experiments nowadays are cheap to run. Why didn't you generate some random matrices to see if your hypothesis is supported by numerical evidence? Anyway, here is a counterexample:
$$
M = \pmatrix{
6&4&3&3\\
4&3&3&3\\
3&3&3&5\\
3&3&5&9}.
$$
All $2\times2$ minors of $M$ are nonnegative, but $\det M = -14 <0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. My bad. Now fixed.